# Error 13 with .Transpose

Tags: vba, excel

```
With WorksheetFunction
    aProducts = .Transpose(.Transpose(aProducts))
    aArticles = .Transpose(.Transpose(aArticles))
End With
```

Hi, guys

This code worked yesterday but not anymore: it still works with "aProducts" but the error 13: type mismatch shows up for "aArticles".

Is it a recurrent error? Do you have any idea why it stoped working?

**EDIT 1**

Link to the file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5DpGwPWsIfbSWlDbkxCVWtMWU0
You just have to run Sub final_code

Remember to rename the dataset 1 or 2 as "Données" if you want to test

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is aArticles? what type of variable is it?

Comment: It's an Array. aProd and aArt are similar. My code for my dataset1 but as I try to run it with another dataset, the error shows up (worked yesterday with dataset  and 2)

Comment: I think you better check your data first, or provide [mcve] to support your question.

Comment: please provide a larger subset of the code

Comment: I don't know if you have a notification when I edit the post so... @Alex

Comment: I cant tag 2 users so... @mo.h

Comment: I got a different error: `unable to get the Match property of the WroksheetFunction class` that was for the aHdr variable. start there perhaps?

Comment: Did the error shows up for a specific index of aHdr? If yes then, is this index 1?

Comment: Aaaaand it's probably for aHdr(1): just rename B1 in "CODE P" instead of "CODP" and it will work

Comment: @mo.h I just find out that the reason of the error message is when the length of my description is over 255 characters. I can now know if it woorks or not but still did not explain why it stoped working from day to day... I don't know if there is a way to "ignore" the limitation of 255 but I can change my code to copy the value in a different way. Anyway, thanks for your time =)

Comment: @Verd'O i did not receive any of your previous replies as you did not tag me. Please rememebr to tag a user so they are notified :) and i think it was index 8

Comment: @mo.h well... I don't remember having this error on aHdr(8) but anyway, the limitation kinda sucks... :/ I will remember to tag people next time ^^